# ¿Para que sirve _('') en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Me he encontrado con una sintaxis diferente en varios codigos, mas que nada solo he visto cuando se utiliza Django, no en Python como tal.

Por ejemplo, al momento de ponerle un `verbose_name` a un campo en Django, lo hacen de la siguiente manera:

```
title = models.CharField(_('Titulo'), max_length = 200)
```

Con esa sintaxis rara de `_('')`, también lo utilizan al momento de poner un `verbose_name` y un `verbose_name_plural` a un modelo, de la siguiente manera:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('app')
    verbose_name_plural = _('apps')
```

Bien lo podrían haber hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'app'
    verbose_name_plural = 'apps'
```

Mas no lo hicieron, entonces, ¿Porque con esa sintaxis?, ¿Tiene ventajas hacerlo de esa manera?, ¿Porque solo lo utilizan cuando se trabaja con Django y no en Python como tal?

Es una duda que he tenido desde siempre, pero nunca he encontrado información sobre ello. De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Te falta algo con lo que quizás entenderías de dónde biene ese _, mira los imports en esos módulos....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que `_()` es un alias global que se usa para `gettext()`

Lee la segunda Nota de la sección Standard Translation de este enlace:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation